# Error correction disabled. Will iTunes report errors it encounters?

Tags: itunes, import

Environment: Windows 7 and iTunes 12

Situation: I want to import a 33-disc audiobook.

In Import Settings, there is a checkbox for correcting errors (such as due to dust and scratches).

I know that using error correction will slow down the import process on older computers.

If I disable error correction, will iTunes alert me in some fashion either during the process or at the end, such as "Import complete but with errors," at which point I can choose to import again but with error correction enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never known it to report errors, unless the read fails totally.

On any reasonably modern machine, error correction takes so little extra effort that it's not worth switching off.
All it does is compares a checksum on the CD itself with one it calculates on the fly. If they match, job done & on to the next track.  If they don't match, then it will try again.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should use a tool like [Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/) (Windows) or [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) (OS X). Only such tools are capable of accurate audio ripping.